# Getting const_iterator from begin() instead of cbegin()

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, overloading, const-iterator

Can someone explain why the following will not compile if I uncomment the line
`foo::const_iterator j = f.begin();`, but if I use the line `foo::const_iterator j = f.cbegin();` it will compile?  I'm trying to get that line to work just as it works with my `std::vector` example.

```
#include <vector>

struct foo {
    struct node { };
    node *first = nullptr, *last = nullptr;

    struct base_iterator {
        node* ptr;
        base_iterator (node* n) : ptr(n) { }
    };

    struct iterator : base_iterator { using base_iterator::base_iterator; };

    struct const_iterator : base_iterator { using base_iterator::base_iterator; };

    iterator begin() { return iterator(first); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(first); }
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return const_iterator(first); }
};

// Test

int main() {
    foo f;
    foo::iterator i = f.begin();
//  foo::const_iterator j = f.begin();  // Won't compile because f is not const.
//  foo::const_iterator j = f.cbegin();  // Will compile fine.

    std::vector<int> v;
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin();  // Compiles even though v is not const.
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to work? Different types, and all. It doesn't happen magically for `vector`. The iterators are designed to have conversions available.

Comment: What do I have to change in my iterator and const_iterator classes to get this to work like `std::vector<int>::const_iterator`?

Comment: Add a converting c'tor, or a conversion operator.

Comment: So define in the `const_iterator` class the operator `const_iterator& operator=(const iterator& other)`, or the analogous copy constructor?

Comment: No, not an assignment operator. A conversion operator. Just gimme a sec

Comment: @prestokeys that isn't a copy constructor. It is a *normal* constructor, that takes a parameter of *some other type*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for `std::vector` because the iterators of all standard library containers are *designed* to support the `iterator` --> `const_iterator` conversion. It's meant to mimic how pointer conversions work.

Whenever your two iterators are user defined classes, you need to add it explicitly. You have two options:

A converting constructor:

```
struct iterator : base_iterator { using base_iterator::base_iterator; };

struct const_iterator : base_iterator {
   using base_iterator::base_iterator;
   const_iterator(const iterator& other) : base_iterator(other) {}
};
```

A conversion operator:

```
struct const_iterator : base_iterator { using base_iterator::base_iterator; };

struct iterator : base_iterator {
  using base_iterator::base_iterator; 
  operator const_iterator() const { /* ... */ }
};
```